# EKEventStore search event with title NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, nspredicate

I have requirement to search events added to iOS calendar with title OR notes. I like to search events with `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title like 'Callback'"]`.

When googled I got `predicateForEventsWithStartDate` only. How can we fetch/search events with title OR notes in iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 predicates to do this

Here a commented example :

```
// you init your store event
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

//you get the list of events
NSPredicate *datePredicate = [store predicateForEventsWithStartDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0] //yesterday
                                                            endDate:[NSDate date] //today
                                                          calendars:nil];
//this will return a list of EKEvent
NSArray<EKEvent *> *events = [store eventsMatchingPredicate:datePredicate];

//you create a second predicate to test on title or wethever you want
NSPredicate *textPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title like 'Callback'"];

//here you will get the events with title like Callback
NSArray<EKEvent *> *results = [events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:textPredicate];
```

Comment: so no other options :-(